# Unknown client accessing Eve API

Tags: ruby, rest, oauth, unirest

I am trying to access Eve Online's CREST API.  I'm trying to get through authorization via SSO as spelled out here: 
http://eveonline-third-party-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sso/authentication.html

I have the authorization code from the initial callback, but the problem arises when sending a post request to get the authorization token. The body of the response is

```
"error"=>"invalid_client", "error_description"=>"Unknown client"
```

I'm using Unirest, and I don't think there's anything wrong with my headers.  Am I missing something?  Is there a silly error here?

```
 headers = { "Authorization" => "Basic #{auth_head}",
          "Content-Type" =>  "application/json",
          "Accept" => "application/json",
          "Host" => "login.eveonline.com"
  }

 params = { "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
         "code" => "#{auth_code}"
}

response = Unirest.post "https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/token", 
                    headers:headers, 
                    parameters:params.to_json
```

The auth_head is a Base64 encoded string using the Base64 encode library in Ruby.  The Client ID and Key are hard-coded into that Base64 translation, so I'm not sure what the issue could be there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been awhile since I posted this, but just in case anybody has this specific issue, my problem was that the Base64 encoding contained newline [`\n`] characters. After deleting them out of the string, everything worked fine. If you come across a resource that tells you it's ok to include them, I can't speak to that for other API's, but it's certainly NOT ok for this one.